# Change variable/type names throughout solution with shortcut?

Tags: resharper

Resharper tends to give a lot of suggestions with regards to naming.

Is there a shortcut to change all the names of variables to Resharper's preferrered convention?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, totally misread your question.

There's obviously Alt-Enter to accept them one by one.

The other option is running Code-Cleanup with a profile that only targets naming.